# How to determine from hardware, when I can shut off a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: gpio, power, power-supply, power-management

I am wiring up a raspberry pi to use a battery supply and I would like it to be a single switch controlling its power. Obviously, I don't want to cut power when its running, but I also don't want two physical switches for both power and halt. Is there a way to have a pin high prior to shutdown and then go low after shutdown?